# Java ScriptEngineManager doesn't properly handle braces

Tags: java, scriptengine

Sample Code:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
System.out.println(engine.eval("{1}/5"));
```

Gives an error of: Expected an operand but found /

Comment: `{1}` creates a JavaScript Object. You can't apply `/` on an `Object`. node.js gives `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /` on the same code. Try valid code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine!

```
 ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 try {
      System.out.println(engine.eval("1/5"));
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can not divide objects by integer in `Javascript` that why your problem occured

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there a way to convert from objects to ints?